# How can I update ContentItem from a background task in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

The ContentItem I'm updating has a bool variable and I only know ContentItem Id. How can I update this variable from controller? I'm planning to send ajax request to the controller and then update.

I have a checkbox and I want to change bool variable when the user clicks it.

I tried to update it with ContentManager.Query() but I failed. This is the part where I'm planning to send the request.

```
$("li").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
        //Make State False $(this).attr("id")
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('checked');
        //Make State True $(this).attr("id")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, assuming you have injected a `IContentManager` instance named `_contentManager`, you should be able to do something like this (I'm assuming what you called a "bool variable" is a Boolean field named "State" under some part):

```
public ActionResult SetState(int contentItemId, bool state) {
    var contentItem = _contentManager.GetLatest(id);
    if (contentItem == null) return HttpNotFound();
    var field = contentItem
        .Parts
        .SelectMany(p => p.Fields)
        .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "State") as BooleanField;
    if (field != null) {
        field.Value = state;
    }
    return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");
}
```